# MVC 4 Ajax.BeginForm binding grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

I use codeplex mvc.grid,i want to bind grid after all dropdownlist selected

My question is SIMPLE :

I m new in mvc development, i have 4 dropboxes and each dropdown triggers next dpdown object to bind values.

How can bind grid using ajaxform.

In case, i want to select first dropdownlist,this action populate second dropdownlist,this action populate next dropdownlist...

Finally when i click to LoadListToGrid button, i dont want REFRESH page,just bind gridview thats all.
 Why i cant do that in mvc, how can i do that plz tell me

Thanks for your helping

---

> View: (CheckList.cshtml)

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CheckList", "Check", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Productresult" }))
{`
<div>Dp1</div>
@Html.DropDownList("dpCompany", ViewBag.CompanyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })

<div>Dp2</div>
@Html.DropDownList("dpBank", ViewBag.CompanyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })

<div>Dp3</div>
@Html.DropDownList("dpStartCheckList", ViewBag.CompanyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })

<div>>Dp4</div>
@Html.DropDownList("dpEndCheckList", ViewBag.CompanyList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })`

  <input type="submit" name="CheckList" value="LoadListToGrid" class="btn btn-default" />    

  @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
  {
     columns.Add(c => c.customer_reference).Titled("Çek No").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.unvan).Titled("Ünvan").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.vergi_no).Titled("Vergi No").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.islem_tarihi).Titled("İşlem Tarihi").SetWidth(30).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
     columns.Add(c => c.currency).Titled("Para Birimi").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.full_curr_amount).Titled("Tutar").SetWidth(30).Format("{0:C}").Css("align-right");
  }).WithPaging(10) } // ajax end
```

> Script

```
$(function () {


                // Company
                $('#dpCompany').on('change', function () {
                    var stateDropdown = $('#dpBank');
                    //disable state drop down
                    stateDropdown.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //clear drop down of old states
                    stateDropdown.empty();

                    //retrieve selected country
                    var company = $(this).val();
                    if (company.length > 0) {
                        // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetBankList")', {
                        company: company
                    })
.done(function (data) {
    //re-enable state drop down
    stateDropdown.removeAttr('disabled');
    //for each returned state
    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
        var values = state.split('|');
        //Create new option
        var option = $('<option value="' + values[0] + '" />').html(values[1]);
        //append state states drop down
        stateDropdown.append(option);
    });

    //if count 1 bind
    if ($("#dpBank option").length == 1) {
        $("#dpBank").trigger("change");
    }
})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
});} });
                //
                $('#dpBank').on('change', function () {
                    var stateDropdown = $('#dpCheckStart');
                    //disable state drop down
                    stateDropdown.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //clear drop down of old states
                    stateDropdown.empty();

                    //retrieve selected country
                    var bank = $(this).val();

                    var company = $("#dpCompany").val();
                    if (company.length > 0) {
                        // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCheckList")', {
                        companyCode: company,
                        bankCode: bank
                    })
.done(function (data) {
    //re-enable state drop down
    stateDropdown.removeAttr('disabled');
    //for each returned state
    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
        var values = state.split('|');
        //Create new option
        var option = $('<option value="' + values[0] + '" />').html(values[1]);
        //append state states drop down
        stateDropdown.append(option);
    });

    //if count 1 bind
    if ($("#dpBank option").length == 1) {
        $("#dpCheckStart").trigger("change");
    }


})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
}) } });


                $('#dpCheckStart').on('change', function () {
                    var stateDropdown = $('#dpCheckEnd');
                    //disable state drop down
                    stateDropdown.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //clear drop down of old states
                    stateDropdown.empty();

                    //retrieve selected country
                    var startOver = $(this).val();
                    if (startOver.length > 0) {
                        // retrieve data using a Url.Action() to construct url
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetListOver")', {
                        startOver: startOver
                    })
.done(function (data) {
    //re-enable state drop down
    stateDropdown.removeAttr('disabled');
    //for each returned state
    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
        var values = state.split('|');
        //Create new option
        var option = $('<option value="' + values[0] + '" />').html(values[1]);
        //append state states drop down
        stateDropdown.append(option);
    })

})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
})}});
```

> Controller

```
public ActionResult CheckList()
{

    ViewBag.Message = "";

    LoadDefaults();

    ViewBag.Loaded = false;
    return View();

}

private void LoadDefaults()
{
    ViewBag.BaseList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    ViewBag.CompanyList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    ViewBag.BankList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    ViewBag.AmountTotalTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult CheckList(FormCollection form)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "";

    ViewBag.StartSelectedItem = StartCheckNo = form["dpStartCheckList"];
    ViewBag.EndSelectedItem = EndCheckNo = form["dpEndCheckList"];


    F8BaseDB.DbSchema.F8BaseSchema.CheckList chk = new F8BaseDB.DbSchema.F8BaseSchema.CheckList();

    LoadDefaults();


    return View(chk.GetAll(ViewBag.StartSelectedItem, ViewBag.EndSelectedItem));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1)create new partial view which will only render grid i.e
_grid.cshtml
//this is partial view
 @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
  {
     columns.Add(c => c.customer_reference).Titled("Çek No").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.unvan).Titled("Ünvan").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.vergi_no).Titled("Vergi No").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.islem_tarihi).Titled("İşlem Tarihi").SetWidth(30).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
     columns.Add(c => c.currency).Titled("Para Birimi").SetWidth(30);
     columns.Add(c => c.full_curr_amount).Titled("Tutar").SetWidth(30).Format("{0:C}").Css("align-right");
  }).WithPaging(10) } // ajax end
//partial view end

create method in controller to return that partial view i.e.
public actionResult _grid(pass dropdown values here)

2)In your main view...
<div id='gridTable'></div>
<input type="button" name="CheckList" value="LoadListToGrid" class="btn btn-default" id="loadgrid" /> 
$('#loadgrid').onclick(function(){ 
//write ajax call here and specify url as  url:'/controllername/_grid'

//in success function write this
success:function(data)
{
$('#gridTable').html(data);
}
});

follow this stape
1)create seperate partial view for grid
2)in ajax call pass dropdown value to partial view and add return html to any Div tag
```